# AngularJs - On ng-click all items get affected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

I'm trying to change the scope when i click on the element but when i do that all the elements get's changed

What im trying to accomplish is when i click on one of the div, i want te color of the div to change to red. this part works fine. Then i also want to the scope to change when i click on one of the divs. What is happening here is that all the scopes are changing.

```
<div  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" ng-repeat="student in stuRegister.students"  ng-click="stuRegister.absneceChange($index, absence)">

    <div id="myDIV{{$index}}" class="card text-white bg-success o-hidden h-100" data-index="{{$index}}">
           <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="mr-5" >
                         <p>{{$index + 1}}. <strong>{{student.name}}</strong></p></div>
                    <div class="mr-5" data-ng-model-options="stuRegister.aData.role" ><strong ng-bind="absence">Status: {{absence[0]}}</strong></div>                                
                        </div>
                   <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
                                    <span class="float-left">Indmeld fravær</span>
                                    <span class="float-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Js:

```
    $scope.absence = "Tilstede";

    this.absneceChange = function(index, absence){
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

        $scope.absence = $scope.absence === "Tilstede" ? "Fravær" : "Tilstede";
        element[index].classList.toggle("bg-danger");
        element[index].classList.toggle("bg-warning");
    }
```

Comment: share your affected html as well. Also, you're accessing DOM directly within angular which is bad, if you share proper code, I'll give you a better way of doing it

Comment: Also, you do not need javascript to accomplish what you're trying to do. Angular's ng-class will do it nicely

Comment: I have inserted the html code

Comment: Where is absneceChange defined ? can there be multiple card divs ?

Comment: Yeah, im using ng-repeat to show multiple cards. i have updated the question, maybe you will understand better.

Comment: can you share the html where absneceChange  is called ?

Comment: I have inserted it in the html

Comment: <div  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" ng-repeat="student in stuRegister.students"  ng-click="stuRegister.absneceChange($index, absence)">

Comment: Try the code from this pen : https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp, let me know if that meets your requirements

Comment: it dosen't really work

Comment: is it still updating classes for all cards ? I don't think so

Comment: the scope for all the cards are all changing on click. i don't want this to happen. I only wants it to change when i click on one of the divs

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the scope for all the cards are all changing on click"

Comment: I mean the $scope.absence

Comment: in the html i have inserted the ng-bind for $scope.absence. and in the js its's = "Something". When i click on one of the cards i want the absence to change to "SomethingElse"

Comment: That is because you have a single scope variable "absense" for all divs, Try the updated solution https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp

Comment: But in you solution you are focusing on something that allready works form me. How can i modify it so that i have multiple scope vaiables that changes on click for only one card and not for every card? 
Thank you very much for your support i really appriciate it :)

Comment: maybe you can give your personal mail or something so that i can send you a screenshot of what i mean

Comment: ajanth2newearth@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent you a mail

Comment: Did you recive my mail ?

Comment: If you want to update an individual student, you should call `stuRegister.absneceChange()` passing student. In your implementation `$scope.absence` is global, not per student.